# Typescript constructor interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface

I've taken this example from [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#implementing-an-interface)

```
interface ClockConstructor {
  new (hour: number, minute: number): ClockInterface;
}

interface ClockInterface {
  tick(): void;
}

function createClock(
  ctor: ClockConstructor,
  hour: number,
  minute: number
): ClockInterface {
  return new ctor(hour, minute);
}

class DigitalClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number, m: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("beep beep");
  }
}

class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor(h: number, m: number) {}
  tick() {
    console.log("tick tock");
  }
}

let digital = createClock(DigitalClock, 12, 17);
let analog = createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32);
```

As the doc says:

> Because createClock’s first parameter is of type ClockConstructor, in createClock(AnalogClock, 7, 32), it checks that AnalogClock has the correct constructor signature.

I wonder that no restriction is applied on not having a constructor, so if I change the `AnalogClock` class like below, Typescript would not give me any errors.

```
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
    // constructor(h: number, m: number) {}  <-- this like commented out.
    tick() {
      console.log("tick tock");
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you don't provide your own constructor, then a default constructor will be supplied for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify constructor explicitly, default constructor will be used instead [according to MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)

```
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
  tick() {
    console.log("tick tock");
  }
}

// is equal to
class AnalogClock implements ClockInterface {
  constructor() {}

  tick() {
    console.log("tick tock");
  }
}
```

As well constructor will inherit `super(...args)` call if you do not specify constructor on child class

```
class Ancestor {
  foo: string;
  
  constructor(foo: string) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

class Child extends Ancestor {
  constructor(foo: string) {
    super(foo);
  }
}

// equals to
class Child extends Ancestor {}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2wCmEAuB7ATtA3gKGkOgDN10AuaNTAS3gHMBuAo4deagV2A0wApSFKqloMAlLhZEiqABY0IAOkHQAvCTLNpAXzy6A9PuiYkAR040TMFQAcwmMAFskqJNgzQARkmh2oSABNoOg82DhFuXjwwtGgwRDVoeCQAdzhEFF4+AHJBbLFmaPAoaAARNxoAN0DoJAAPV3gAmARkNCxJaQUAYXkQIPUIpGYDIzdMLBgU2SR4JPRfeycXNxg-CEDo9liAiuqBpNSyvcCcvIK8PENoEHR6GFyybK2OdBAkRVv6Pl3afeUyBcrkYALRg8EQyFQ6Ew2EQq4AKgRBARcBAEAWwD6QVAkCmNBAIEONVCYEJVE4NjctTqNhANGANFQIAAnijgsRoCz0JxiUFHFgfHYHI4YB5vIt-EEQpjthEeFgUfoinj0ug5G5yn8avVGs10m1eJ0iJ57JR4JxHN5MFoiNdxpMOdAAAYQSluZ3BGDwdXQYBk94BKR+uWYSJYARkSjUOj0AA0XjNSUt1ok+Gk0jdVP4gguGZk8iUpuw6mLtsIul0L1i8XVM0wWqqNXUyTSCDrmpOATOTwTAEYAExiYE3O4PPLQQfVt4fL58WsahtdgHoBML+uN-7F4cjuF7-cH8GI5HQVEAFRZVIgwFoNlQ0FkkCosiwqGAnHvHnWfuKawmNggdkZRDcIwwVbBSHcGZHGgcUhXAZAggCSwkB4Vl2RSJkXw-KgqUZYgWVjF05AUFdEkET16jpBkmXQ09oHZAAxDomVghYUiwABrLkeT5NjcNQmgCLiYA2hgAVkOIBkwCiejIOCRB0EcIiYnlI1hScJUVRKABlJSkG6X9jUIVSwKyYNpBsThPHpYBfGs2yAAV-2jERYzjCyiBsP4ZKFHzXGc9AbHNFM3A8-NCG89VUNcIIotcHhAkC4LhFEeNgzTStq3vDFnESVtoD05xDLxHIrM8bJ+wTbJB3yEdvKqXy4iaXwJgS2LWqCmB-XgbJ7wlMBRJQDYg2uL4HnK54YhnT47j4XKPnKpz-x3XFdP0zdAhKkpdVmfUioMoz01YR8GCQQL2qS-8+DTTzCGueKYpqKKbD9eIvB8QaxJqOg-WxH88RQO7YMLRRHsSgJksSbIsXiehAgAQmyctoErIA)

Comment: and does the default constructor's schema match the schema `ClockConstructor` defined?

Comment: Yes, it does. Added playground link with better explanation to the answer above